# Canceling Edit on question still puts it on edit queue

Tags: support, questions, edits

I started editing a question from another user and decided to cancel. Then when I went on the question page again, the `edit` button was greyed out and the edit was put on the queue.

It seems like this is a problem for 2K+ users but I am nowhere close to being 2K...

[Pointers and dynamic memory allocation in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472106/pointers-and-dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c)

Comment: Are you sure that it was your edit that was placed on the queue, and not someone who suggested an edit right after you cancelled?

Comment: I am not sure, can two edits be done concurrently?

Comment: It's happened before. Plus, I just checked your profile; there's only one suggestion I see, and it's from 4 days ago.

Comment: Yes I also checked my profile and no edits were done. So that must be it

Comment: @hazer_drum it's certainly possible to have multiple concurrent edits.

Comment: @Sklivvz I suppose in that case the first one that confirms the edit gets placed on the queue and the latter one gets denied?

Comment: No actually, I've seen two concurrent edits, with one substantial, one minor, and the substantial one gets approved, making the other one look like a vandalizing edit when I review it.

Comment: Can you post link to the question?

Comment: I added the link. Now I tried editing and canceling again and it did not put it on the queue. It must have been a concurrent edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for an unlimited number of users to be editing a post at one time. The first person who submits their edit is the one who gets the cheese.

There is no record of a suggested edit from you on that post. It was simply another user that had suggested an edit, which was unrelated to you deciding to cancel yours.